# What is an “OSE build” for software?

Tags: github, build, terminology, open-source, sourceforge

Recently, I've seen the term “OSE build” a few times for software.

The most recent example is on this page for [Swiss File Knife](https://sourceforge.net/projects/swissfileknife/files/1-swissfileknife/1.9.7.2/):

Note the term “OSE build” is used for only one of the items listed:

```
sfk.exe              Swiss File Knife for Windows (32/64 bits).

sfk-x64.exe          SFK x64 for 64 bit Windows only **(OSE build)**.
sfk-winxp.exe        SFK 32 bits for Windows XP systems.

sfk-linux-64.exe     SFK for 64 bits Intel Linux, like Ubuntu 64.
sfk-mac-64.exe       SFK for current Intel based Macs.
sfk-arm.exe          SFK for ARM systems like Raspberry Pi.

sfktray-set-up.exe   The SFKTray Status Display Tool for Windows,
                     Freeware edition, for use with sfk status.
```

What does this mean?

Performing some searching yielded the possibility of “Open Source Edition”, but all the software projects on that page are open source, so it doesn't seem like it would make sense to label only one of them as an “Open Source Edition?” I'm thinking it’s more likely it means something else.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess. Per this page http://stahlworks.com/dev/x64/ "this is an experimental binary". Maybe just looking for some separation if something goes boom. I actually just downloaded it. I've played with there previous version before. Used it in couple of batch files and made them a little fancier than I would usually.

The worst thing for me was it does SO MUCH.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  It's amazing how much it can do.  Really incredible tool!  A "pro tip" is to save the output of the help system to a text file and use it as a handy-dandy reference.